# Which Is the Used Size Unit In DiskSpace Column at Storage Table In Zoneminder Database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, phpmyadmin

Trying here, without success change the storage location of Zoneminder events and images, but having trouble with denied access of `www-data` user, despite have already changed both Zoneminder config and destination directory.

Now seeking here in `phpMyAdmin` if it could be some sort of database error, once `Zoneminder` error log acuses zero disk space, even with something about 400Gb free.

My tryout now is change manualy the `DiskSpace` column in `phpMyAdmin`, once it could be had been determinated during installation and now it kind of stuck.

Need to know which is the unit used in `DiskSpace` column, once it acuses the value of 59289474877 and Storage tab in Zoneminder shows `310.4GB of 365.68GB` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

59289474877 Bytes => 55.21 GByte .. pretty much the difference between 365.68 and 310.4

so the unit is Bytes if that helps..